# Crear VirtualHost para dominios

Tags: apache

Tengo 26 virtual-host para subdominios (se crearon tipo A, no tipo CNAME) de una página con dominio "ejemplo1.com" (no se estaba usando el dominio) y necesito crearle el virtualhost a ese dominio

En etc `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` esas 26 virtualhost tienen esta forma:

```
<VirtualHost subdomain1.ejemplo1.com:80>
    ServerAdmin <correo@other_example.com>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/subdomain1/

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/subdomain1/django.wsgi

    Alias /static/ /var/www/html/subdomain1/static/

    <Directory /var/www/html/subdomain1>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/html/subdomain1/static>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ServerName subdomain1.ejemplo1.com
```

También cometí el error de editar el `000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin <correo@other_example.com>
    #ServerName ejemplo1.com
    #ServerAlias www.ejemplo1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ejemplo1_com/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Pero no ha tomado el contenido de esa carpeta

En `/etc/hosts` tengo esto:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost  
ip_example1     otro_name_host        nombre_empresa  
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback  
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes  
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Sinceramente no sé qué son esos parámetros, esa configuración ya estaba así.

Necesito 2 cosas:
1. corregir el `000-default.conf` o eliminarlo y crear un `ejemplo1_com.conf`
2. crear un `ejemplo2_com.conf` (es otro dominio totalmente distinto) y su virtualhost. Añadiendo su info a `/etc/hosts`

Comment: Podrias mostrarnos como que el archivo `000-default.conf`

Comment: Una sugerencia para administrarlo de manera sencilla te recomiendo utilizar Virtualmin.

Comment: ¿Intentaste hacerlo de la misma manera como creabas los virtualhost para los subdominios?
Los contenidos de `etc/hosts` déjalos así...

Answer (score 5):

No has dado mucho detalle sobre tu configuración actual pero en la página de Apache existen varios ejemplos que seguro te pueden ayudar.

- Correr varios sitios por nombre en la misma dirección IP:

  ```
  # Asegurar que Apache escuche en el puerto 80
  Listen 80
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
      ServerName www.example.com

      # Otras directivas
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
      ServerName www.example.org

      # Otras directivas
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- Sitios por nombre en mas de una dirección IP:

  ```
  Listen 80

  # Este es el servidor principal corriendo en 172.20.30.40
  ServerName server.example.com
  DocumentRoot "/www/mainserver"

  <VirtualHost 172.20.30.50>
      DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
      ServerName www.example.com

      # Otras directivas
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost 172.20.30.50>
      DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
      ServerName www.example.org

      # Otras directivas
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- Correr diferentes sitios en puertos distintos:

  ```
  Listen 80
  Listen 8080

  <VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80>
      ServerName www.example.com
      DocumentRoot "/www/domain-80"
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:8080>
      ServerName www.example.com
      DocumentRoot "/www/domain-8080"
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80>
      ServerName www.example.org
      DocumentRoot "/www/otherdomain-80"
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:8080>
      ServerName www.example.org
      DocumentRoot "/www/otherdomain-8080"
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- Sitios virtuales basados en IP:

  ```
  Listen 80

  <VirtualHost 172.20.30.40>
      DocumentRoot "/www/example1"
      ServerName www.example.com
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost 172.20.30.50>
      DocumentRoot "/www/example2"
      ServerName 
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

Para más ejemplos:

- [VirtualHost Examples](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html)

### Actualización

Sobre el archivo `/etc/hosts`, si no estás usando IPv6 puedes dejar esta parte tal y como está actualmente:

```
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback  
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes  
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

El funcionamiento de `/etc/hosts` es muy sencillo, si ya tienes levantado el servicio de Apache y haces algo como esto para efectos de prueba:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   example.com
```

Puedes ingresar a estas URLs y el servicio de Apache las reconocerá:

- http://localhost
- http://example.com

Ten en cuenta que http://example.com es un sitio verdadero pero nos sirve de ejemplo para mostrar el funcionamiento de Apache y `/etc/hosts`.

Habiendo dicho esto, lo que necesitas hacer es configurar de acuerdo a las reglas que has definido para los `VirtualHost`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   subdomain1.ejemplo1.com ejemplo1.com
127.0.0.1   subdomain2.ejemplo2.com ejemplo2.com
127.0.0.1   subdomain3.ejemplo3.com ejemplo3.com
# ...
```

Comment: No es lo que necesito, revisa porfa mi edición y me ayudas porfa, puse más detalles

Comment: @DianaCarolinaHernandez actualicé mi respuesta, me comentas

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la info de `/etc/hosts`

Comment: cómo se maneja el archivo `/etc/hosts` ?  sólo con 2 parámetros?
porque tengo dudas es sobre los puertos, no sé si es ahí o en el archivo en sí de cada virtualhost... no creo que 2 dominios distintos apuntando al mismo servidor (de hosting -es propio-) puedan escuchar por el mismo puerto... actualmente me funciona sólo uno

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con una configuración así:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/ejemplo1.conf
```

Y agregas:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@ejemplo1.com
    ServerName example1.com
    ServerAlias www.example1.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/ejemplo1_com/

</VirtualHost>
```

Luego no olvides:

**Para decirle a apache que active el virtualhost**

```
a2ensite ejemplo1
```

**Luego reiniciar el servicio de apache2**

```
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: ¿No sería `a2ensite ejemplo1` sin más?

Comment: No @CésarBustíos, por lo general apache necesita ser reiniciado para que lea los cambios, eso lo único que hace es habilitar el virtualhost, más no lo lee aún.
`a2ensite` simplemente los agrega.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21812360/what-is-the-difference-between-sites-enabled-and-sites-available-directory

Comment: Si eso lo se, me refería a la sintáxis del comando `a2ensite`, tu pusiste `example.com.conf` pero el archivo se llama `ejemplo1.conf`

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. No me fijé...
Ya mismo edito.

Comment: Mira si de pronto tienes otro virtualhost apuntando hacia la carpeta que está mostrando ahora el dominio...

Comment: no, era configuración del virtualhost, el del otro dominio adicional ya está bien en producción, gracias